# multiple document.ready within asset pipeline

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, asset-pipeline

I am trying to organize my controller specific code into various javascript files that are then compiled through the asset pipeline. Some of my functions require the DOM to be loaded so I place them within a ready function like this: `$(document).ready(function () { alert("loaded") });`

For some reason this is not being executed when I remove it from the main application.js document.ready function and place it in the respective file. Is it not possible to make multiple calls to the document.ready function within the asset pipeline?

I am using rails 3.2.0, ruby 1.9.3p429 and jquery-rails (3.0.1)

Here are the application.js sprocket comments:

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require_self
//= require_tree .
```

Comment: The problem should be some place else since you can add as many document ready handlers as you want

Comment: Are you requiring your new files inside the sprockets comments?

Comment: hmm yes I have `//= require_tree .` which adds the sidebar.js file and when I put a simple `alert("hi")` without the document wrap it works.

Comment: I think I'd need to see some actual code to fully understand what you're trying to do here.

Comment: okay I just created another simple scaffold application with the same problem I will add to the question

Comment: okay actually the problem with my scaffold generation was I had a coffee script comment from when I changed it to a .js file, this shows it must be something to do with my old application. I will look into it some more!

Comment: fixed it I will post the solution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that by removing the `//= require_self` comment, the `$(document).ready` function works. I originally upgraded to 3.1 with this [railscasts episode](http://railscasts.com/episodes/282-upgrading-to-rails-3-1). In his code he includes that line but I noticed in my newly generated scaffold 3.1 app it was not present. I am not sure what the purpose of require_self is but removing it fixed the issue!

Thanks guys!

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried using the jQuery shortcut for document ready? `$(function(){ alert("loaded") });`
It has the same functionality. Also, you should probably update to rails 3.2.13 as there are some major security updates between 3.2.0 and 3.2.13

Comment: thanks will upgrade also didn't know about that shortcut, thanks!